# Elegant way to implement INotifyPropertyChanged across many controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm building a WPF application and I'm slowly uncovering some of the joys and also the frustrations of using WPF. My latest question involves updating the UI using `INotifyPropertyChanged`

My app has stacked UserControls with each `UserControl` containing multiple controls, so overall there are hundreds of controls which update every second providing live data. In order to update all controls I'm using something similar to below which does currently work as intended.

```
namespace ProjectXAML
{
    public partial class ProjectX : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


#region Declare Getter/Setter with INotifyPropertyChanged groupx3

        private string m_group1Text1;
        public string group1Text1
        {
            get
            {
                return m_group1Text1;
            }
            set
            {
                m_group1Text1 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("group1Text1");
            }
        }

        private string m_group1Text2;
        public string group1Text2
        {
            get
            {
                return m_group1Text2;
            }
            set
            {
                m_group1Text2 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("group1Text2");
            }
        }

        private string m_group2Text1;
        public string group2Text1
        {
            get
            {
                return m_group2Text1;
            }
            set
            {
                m_group2Text1 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("group2Text1");
            }
        }

        private string m_group2Text2;
        public string group2Text2
        {
            get
            {
                return m_group2Text2;
            }
            set
            {
                m_group2Text2 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("group2Text2");
            }
        }

        private string m_group3Text1;
        public string group3Text1 
        { 
            get
            {
                return m_group3Text1;
            }
            set
            {
                m_group3Text1 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("group3Text1");
            }
        }

        private string m_group3Text2;
        public string group3Text2
        {
            get
            {
                return m_group3Text2;
            }
            set
            {
                m_group3Text2 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("group3Text2");
            }
        }

 #endregion

 #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// Notifies the property changed.
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
 #endregion

}
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a more elegant way to raise `PropertyChanged` events for lots of controls rather than lots of get/set code?
2. Is there a way to raise 1 `PropertyChanged` event covering the whole `UserControl` containing multiple controls instead of a separate event for every control? Is there a better method than what I'm attempting?

Comment: Not that I know of.  And I always add a if (x == value) return; for speed.   The idea of property level is so the control only repaints what it has to.   There is some overhead as I had NotifyPropertyChanged in a loop once (and it did not need to be there) and got an out of memory error.

Comment: You would normally use Dependency properties on controls. Any reason you don not?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - The XAML controls use `Text="{Binding group1Text1}` if that's what you mean by dependency properties?

Comment: No, I meant [Dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx). And they include INPC. But I find it confusing these are on a UserControl, they look like part of a Model.

Comment: If you do NotifyPropertyChanged(null); then this informs the listener of INotifyPropertyChanged that all properties have changed on an object.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - it's not part of the model. This code sets/gets strings which has binding to TextBlock which sits inside a Button.

Comment: I'm still doubtful. Is group1Text1 self data-bound? (IE as Target as well as Source).

Comment: @colinsmith - thanks Colin. Your suggestion is working fine in my instance. Whether that's the right way of doing things..? I'll definitely need to read up more on MVVM as everyone is suggesting.

Comment: That actually means it's only used as a source. But your live will become easier when you move it to a VM.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I've still got some learning to do when it comes to WPF. Thanks for you help.

Comment: It's not the usual way....it's possibly a more efficient way if you are always updating all properties anyway....saves lots of individual notifications...it's a trick that batches it into one....but it causes all Bindings to propertifes to be updated....so is less efficient when you are only changing a few properties.

Comment: All of them are updated so I think it is justified in this instance.. for now. If you put it as an answer I'll accept as I think it probably answers my specific questions. Now on to some VM reading....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In strict reference to this part of your question..."Is there a way to raise 1 PropertyChanged event covering the whole UserControl containing ".

Yes, you can raise a PropertyChanged notification which says all my properties on my object are updated.

Use:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged(null);
```

then this informs the listener of INotifyPropertyChanged that all properties have changed on an object.

This isn't normally used...and can be abused....and cause inefficient updates e.g. if you were only changing a few properties and used that.

But you could argue the case for using it if you have lots of properties in your object, that you were always changing anyway at the same time...and you wanted to collapse lots of individual notifications into 1 that was raised after you had modified all properties.

Example use case (i.e. presumes you are updating all your groups in some way):

```
void UpdateAllGroupTextProperties()
{
    group1Text1 = "groupA";
    group1Text2 = "groupA2";
    group2Text1 = "groupB";
    group2Text2 = "groupB2";
    group3Text1 = "groupC";
    group3Text2 = "groupC2";
    NotifyPropertyChanged(null);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For point 1 if you are using VS 2012 you can do the below

```
private void SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = "")
{
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
    {
        field = value;
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can use your set property method without having to hard code the name of the properties.

Note the above code is an except of the below link
http://danrigby.com/2012/03/01/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-5-way/

Answer (score 3):

Use the design pattern [model view controler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). So the model will raise the changes for you. Together with [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVVM) the controls will see with its dependency objects the changes and view them automatically.

Comment: What's the problem with this anwer? This is a very generic problem with can be sloved with a design pattern.

Comment: He's asking how to avoid repeating `NotifyPropertyChanged()` calls everywhere.

Comment: But actually the OPs setup looks strange, MVVM might be a good hint.